# Mule- error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'magento:config'

Tags: maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to run in Anypoint Studio a project with maven using magento connector ver 2.2.0.

This is my project's xml file:

```
<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:magento="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento/current/mule-magento.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
 <magento:config name="Magento" username="test" password="test$" address="http://127.0.0.1:8000.com/api/v2_soap/" doc:name="Magento"/>
<flow name="magentoFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/magento" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <magento:get-product config-ref="Magento" doc:name="Magento" productId="1"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

and this is the error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'magento:config'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-empty-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":set-payload, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected.
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule
    xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
    xmlns:magento="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.7/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.7/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento/1.2/mule-magento.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/3.7/mule-json.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <magento:config name="Magento" username="test" password="test$" address="http://127.0.0.1:8000.com/api/v2_soap/" doc:name="Magento"/>
    <flow name="magentoFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/magento" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <magento:get-product config-ref="Magento" doc:name="Magento" productId="1"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Changes from your snippet:

1. Added the XML declaration line
2. Changed the location of the XSDs to specific versions instead of 'current'.
   (Am not sure if this is needed since the XSDs might be coming from jars on the classpath)